# my pip doesn't download packages properly

Tags: python, numpy, cmd, pip

I am trying to install numpy in the command prompt and it is returning an error

I have tried `pip install numpy` but it doesn't work. I have python 3.7.2 and pip 18.1. The problem also occurs with other downloads and such things. I have tried upgrading python, with no success.

```
C:\Users\riley>pip install numpy
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))': /simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate 
(_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping
```

This is always coming up when trying to use pip. why is this?
(btw how do I format the indent space when pasting the code into the page like above?).
The problem might be to do with the link that pip is trying to use (https://pypi.org/simple/pip/) leads to a 404 error on the page.
follow the link and see what you find if you want.

Comment: try it with a lower python version like 3.5.x

Comment: Maybe you are missing a Proxy? Have you googled the error message?

Comment: Your DNS is probably misconfigured or missing a proxy. Can you access Pypi's website? As a temporary fix try turning off your Wi-Fi and run the command as soon as you turn it back on.

Comment: `pip install numpy --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org`, but this only a workaround; you need to fix your system certs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are under a proxy...
This happened to me in my daily routine at work,
the best option for this is to:

1. Access https://pypi.org/simple/
2. Find your lib
3. Download the version you want...

**Numpy:**
https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/

Comment: how do i know which numpy i need because there is hundreds of them

Comment: You need to know your pc stats and python version. E.g: numpy-1.16.0-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl => This is a numpy version 1.16-0, python version 3.7, and windows 32 bits.